# Notation regarding inverse function

Tags: functions, notation, computer-science, inverse-function

I would like to know the correct notation of inverse function because I want to show that $min(f(x)) \equiv max(f^{-1}(x))$. My colleague corrects me that I should write $min(f(x)) \equiv max(-f(x))$.

Can you please tell my which one is correct? or both?  Than you for your answer and explanation.

Best regards,

Comment: See [Inverse function: Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Notation) for the comment about possible misunderstanding.

Comment: Functional inverse is usually denoted $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Both are incorrect.

**Counterexample to the first one :** $f(x)=x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$.

One has $\min_{x \geq 0} f(x) = 0$, but $\max_{x \geq 0} f^{-1}(x)=\max_{x \geq 0} \sqrt{x}$ is undefined.

**Counterexample to the second one :** $f(x)=x$ on $[1,2]$.

One has $\min_{1 \leq x \leq 2} f(x)=1$, but $\max_{1 \leq x \leq 2} -f(x) = -1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but can you please which one is correct in terms of notation? Since I'm dealing with QUBO (Quadratic unconstrained binary optimization) and therefore it should be possible to inverse function.